# Making bars with GraphView

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I have been using `Graphview` for some time and mostly `LineGraph` and `PointGraph`, link to `GraphView` can be found here: [Link to GraphView](http://www.android-graphview.org/line-graph/).

But now I need a `LineGraph` that would fill the whole 0-100 and 100-200 when needed. For example when the point is 70, it would fill the whole 0-100 space, which would look something like this.

Another requirement is that is still needs to be like a `LineGraph` since it needs to be able to move to the right.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done using `GraphView` or if it can be done at all with `GraphView`.

Or maybe if I set the point to be 50 and line thickness so it would cover exactly +/- 50 then it would also be the same but the problem here is that the line thickness is different on every screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom shape for the PointGraphSeries to get the effect that you like. In the following code I am creating a custom rectangle. This can give you some ideas on what to do:

```
int mX = 0;

private void addPoints(double point, PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series) {
    point = Math.floor(point / 100) * 100;
    DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(mX++, point);
    series.appendData(dataPoint, false, 100);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
    // Set manual X bounds
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(10);


    // Set manual Y bounds
    graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinY(0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxY(1000);

    // Set up the number of division for horizontal and vertical units
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(11);
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumVerticalLabels(11);

    PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new PointsGraphSeries<>();

    series.setCustomShape(new PointsGraphSeries.CustomShape() {
        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas,
                         Paint paint,
                         float x,
                         float y,
                         DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
            canvas.drawRect(x, y - 100, x + 175, y, paint);
        }
    });

    int[] points = {450, 512, 323, 240, 70, 790};
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        addPoints(points[i], series);
    }

    graph.addSeries(series);
}
```

This will give you the following picture based on the provided points:

[image]